# Java Objectify : I miss something about Parent and Children

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I'm new to the appengine and I miss something about the Parent-Children relationship. And of course documentation is as always very light...

I defined this

```
@Entity
public class StockRow {

  @Parent Key<StockTable> table;
  @Id Long id;
  Long quantity;
  String status;
  String type;
  String table;

  private StockRow () {}

  public StockRow (String tableName, com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity queryResult) {

    id = queryResult.getKey().getId();
    quantity = (Long) queryResult.getProperty("quantity");
    status = (String) queryResult.getProperty("status");
    type = (String) queryResult.getProperty("stock-name");

    table = StockTable = Key.create(StockTable.class, tableName);

  }
}
```

(I supress the getters for here)

This is the Children : a row.

Then the Parent

```
@Entity
public class StockTable {

  @Id public String table;

  private StockTable () {}
}
```

Pretty simple.

I have two questions about this :

I want to have a table of several rows. A table contains rows with the same id.
So the ID of Stocktable is the ID shared by all its rows.

1) Is it the correct way to do ?

StockRow s must be entities because I query them from Datastore.
Maybe it's Container but I do not understand it...

Or maybe it's useless to define a parent ?

2) How to load all the children for a given id ?

I read this on Objectif wiki but the purpose of this query is not very clear :

```
Thing th = ofy().load().type(Thing.class).parent(par).id(123L).now();
```

I don't know what is inside `par` first and secondly I have the impression that this load is not what I want.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your design seems fine. An entity is uniquely identified by its kind, its ancestor, and its string or numeric ID. Using your current model, suppose you create a StockTable entity with "A" as its name (marked by the table field in your Java class). Then, you add StockRow entities with IDs 100 and 200.

The StockTable key would be:

```
[StockTable/"A"]
```

The StockRow keys would be:

```
[StockTable/"A", StockRow/100]
[StockTable/"A", StockRow/200]
```

Objectify lets you query on these keys by specifying each piece individually:

```
List<StockRow> rows = ObjectifyService.ofy()
    .type(StockRow.class)
    .ancestor(Key.create(StockTable.class, "A"))
    .id(100)
    .list();
```

You would also be able to query for all StockRow entities in StockTable "A" by leaving out the `.id(...)` call.

As for the question: "Or maybe it's useless to define a parent?"

There's a good reason for defining ancestors beyond design reasons. The "top level" entities without ancestors define "entity groups." In your example, each unique StockTable would represent an entity group. Datastore queries within a single entity group (e.g. read all StockRows within this StockTable) guarantee strongly consistent results, so you know they're up to date. Queries that return results across multiple entity groups only guarantee eventually consistent results, which may not be up to date and may not reflect a single, consistent snapshot of your data. You can read more about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency).

Comment: Thanks, i undertand now the interest of making it. But something bothers me in what you said, : two entities of the same kind cannot share the same key ? Because I think i chose a key which is not primary in my dataflow job so that I will have uncomplete data in that case... About my initial question, I corrected my code but I do not know if it works because I did not deployed it, it will need some more time.

Comment: Do you mean that the "id" field in StockRow is not a primary key? Remember that the kind and ancestory as part of the key as well, so as long as it's unique within "table", you should be okay. If not, then you'll need to define a single unique key.

Comment: Thanks, so I have a problem here, I will compute an artificial key for StockRows in datastore becasue I do not have all data. For Objectify finally I will not use it tough it works now but thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a correct way. `StockTable` is a parent, that have multiple `StockRow`, and row ids are uniq only per table.

To load all children for a table:

```
StockTable table = ...;
List<StockRow> rows = ofy().load()
                           .type(StockRow.class) //target type
                           .ancestor(table) //parent entity or just key
                           .list(); //all of them
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I updated my code. I still need to test the whole UI, I did not deployed it yet (will be in some more time). So that I do not know if the whole thing work !